# Mathematical and empirical analysis of AES

Tags: encryption, aes, block-cipher, symmetric

Hello everyone and happy new year in advance.

I'm doing a work about the analysis of the AES algorithm, and I have some doubts about this.

First, I need to do the mathematical analysis of the algorithm:

**Determine the computational complexity, worst-case, average-case and best-case**

As AES performs n numbers of rounds (10, 12, or 14) and we have a loop, I made a summation for an iterative algorithm, and I have this:

$\sum_{i=1}^m 1=n$,

So, my conclusion is that, if I want to encrypt n number of bytes, the most, the average, and the least number of bytes that I must encrypt is n, I cannot encrypt more or less than that. Therefore:

$n \in O(n)$

$n \in \theta(n)$

$n \in \Omega(n)$

My conclusion is that, the cases (worst-average and best) are equivalent and AES have a linear complexity (depends on the number of bytes that I want to encrypt).

**Determine de design paradigm**

I don't know if this question is clear for you, I need to determine if AES is in one of the following design paradigm: Brute Force, Divide and Conquer, Decrease and Conquer, or Transform and Conquer

My analysis:

AES is designed to work in blocks of 16 bytes, and if we have more than 16 bytes it is supposed to DIVIDE the text in blocks of 16 bytes and work with each block until the whole text is encrypted.

Therefore, my conclusion is that AES has a Divide and Conquer design paradigm; and going deeper, is a divide and conquer by a constant factor (16).

I would really appreciate your opinion, and corrections, if necessary, to my analysis and conclusions.

**Do the empirical analysis of the algorithm, and see if it is consistent with the mathematical results**

For the empirical analysis, my idea is just to measure the runtime with different number of bytes, then fit a curve and see if it is linear. If you can suggest, maybe, a better or more advance way to do this, it would be great.

I would really appreciate your opinion and help with this.

Thanks again, and happy new year.

Comment: Why not Transform and Conquer? AES uses substitution, shiftrows, MixColumns. (Confusion and Diffusion)

Comment: I agree, the divide and conquer is not wrong per se, but it is more indicative of a block cipher in a mode of operation than the AES cipher itself.

Comment: Complexity is wrong too, for the same reason. AES is a block cipher, so it encrypts exactly one fixed-sized block of data with a fixed-size key (for any of the 3 variants). It's always O(1). And in cryptography, we don't generally ignore the constant terms, AES and other ciphers MUST take a constant number of CPU cycles on any given processor to be secure. It's possible to implement AES in such a way that it's not constant-time while it's still O(1), those implementations are unsafe.

Comment: The complexity analysis is not mathematical analysis. It uses Math. Counting the number of operations of AES is extensively performed when an attack needs to be compared against the brute-force. These articles can be found [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76738/18298). Oher than that, we usually inplement and show that why this is faster then the others.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was undecided between Divide and Transform but I think you are right. About the complexity, @SAIPeregrinus yes, that was my initial idea, I though it's constant, but I read some documentation and even a post [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26151/computational-complexity-class-of-decryption-of-aes)  where says it is linear because AES encrypts plaintext and if the amount of text increases, it also increases the runtime  because there are more blocks to encrypt. I'm not saying you're wrong, it is just what I found; I'm still confused/undecided about it.

Comment: AES *by definition* encrypts 128 bits of binary data. That's ALL. It's a constant input, it can't increase or decrease. AES can be used as a component of a "block cipher mode of operation" to encrypt more plaintext. EG AES-CTR or AES-GCM. Those ciphers (which are NOT AES, they just use AES) have linear time complexity with the length of the plaintext, because they're repeating the constant complexity of AES for a number of blocks equal to the plaintext length in bits / 128. That's a linear operation, so it's linear complexity. But that's not AES's complexity.

Comment: I understand the answers, but what on earth does OP mean when they say “I have this $\sum_{i=1}^m 1=n$“.  All those other complexity equations displayed later hold trivially.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your help. I have one last question about AES; my professor just told me that I must take in mind the memory, he told me this ''We haven't seen this in depth, but this algorithm uses intermediate memory storage, you should analyze that (memory analysis) too if you can.  Try to find the right example to show this''. As you can read, we haven't studied that yet, so I would really appreciate if you can give me a guide about how to do this; a link, a book, an article, everything will be helpful.                                              Thanks again, and happy new year